# mysql, select Distinct still returning multile items

Tags: mysql, distinct

I'm trying to do a mysql query to get a Distinct number of values.

my query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `videos` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%lovelace%'
```

it's still returning results with the same title,

i tried to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Title`,* FROM `videos` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%lovelace%'
```

but it did not work, can anyone help?

I'd like it to return the whole row (*), but with a distinct rule on the title,

regards

Comment: `DISTINCT` filters duplicate *rows* not *columns*.

Comment: how can i do it then?

Comment: I have duplicate rows with the same Title, but i want it to only show one, instead of duplicate, maybe i worded the question wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find it helpful to create a more rigorous specification of what you require from your query.

Guessing, it seems your `videos` table contains some duplicates; otherwise `SELECT *` would do what you need.  So, guessing, it seems like you're looking for a query to eliminate duplicates.

The question is, how do you define a duplicate?  If you have two rows with the same `Title` it means you have two listings for that particular video.  Presumably you want to display just one of them. Which one? How can distinguish the one you want to display from the one you want to omit?

`SELECT DISTINCT` is pretty good for eliminating duplicates in a simple way. But it's not very sophisticated.  If your table has a primary key, perhaps called `id`, `SELECT DISTINCT *` will not find any duplicates, because there aren't any (every id is different from the previous one, of course).

Pro tip:  avoid using `SELECT *` in your programs. Avoid specifications that say you need "everything out of the query." Instead, in your query name the columns you actually need to appear in your result set.

If you do a query like this

```
    SELECT DISTINCT Title,
                    Director,
                    Year
               FROM videos
              WHERE Title LIKE '%lovelace%'
```

you may actually get the result you're looking for.  But it's hard to help with the actual query because you haven't disclosed the columns in your table.

Answer (score 5):

Use GROUP BY title  instead of DISTINCT

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM `videos` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%lovelace%'
```

Edit:-

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `Title` LIKE '%lovelace%' GROUP BY TITLE
```

Comment: that works, but i need everything out of the query, not just title